# running script at boot time in windows azure vm

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, startup

I have to run ansible playbook at the provisioning of windows vm and it should run every time as the system restart.

I didn't get any functionality in azure vm.

Please suggest how to acheive this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Restart-AzureRmVM
       [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
       [-Name] <String>
       [-AsJob]
       [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
       [<CommonParameters>]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/restart-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: Restart-AzureRmVM doesn't fit the scenario of running the script at boot time